# How to show video thumbnail in Facebook share popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios7, sharing

In the gallery when i am clicking on share video then its showing like that -

[image]

How can i achieve this, I searched a lot but not get any proper solution, I am using this code for sharing popup -

> ```
>     NSString *url_string = @"Video Url";
> ```

```
    SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"Test title"];

    [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];

    if (mediaType == 1]) {
        // Add Image For Image sharing  
        [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImageUtils drawWatermark_in_Image:self.imageView.image]];
    }
    else {
        // Add video thumnail here
    }

    [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Post Canceled");
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                NSLog(@"Post Sucessful");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];

    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MPMoviePlayerController class.  If I remember correctly the requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes() method will return thumbnail images X seconds into the file (you specify how many seconds into the file you want it to perform the capture).

If nothing else, it might point you in the right direction if it turns out it won't work for your particular needs.

Comment: I have thumbnail, I want to know how i can show in share popup like attached image.